# Capturing a String Within a String

Tags: sql-server, parsing, substring, charindex

I am trying to parse out values from a text string. The values are nested within the string. For example, I get flat files that look something like this: "John Q Public (12345-01) - Customer referral". I want to parse out the account number; e.g., 12345-01, from the text string. The starting position isn't constant nor is the length of the account number. The pattern is #####-##.

Any help would be most appreciated.

Comment: Are the values you want always wrapped with parenthesis? And are they always the only parenthesis in the strings?

Comment: Are the numbers always numbers (no alpha-numerics except for the single hyphen)? Will there ever be any OTHER numbers in the string, that are NOT the account number?

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some basic string manipulation will capture the values you want. No idea if this works in your real situation because I have no idea how "stable" or consistent your data is.

```
declare @Something varchar(100) = 'John Q Public (12345-01) - Customer referral'

select substring(@Something
    , charindex('(', @Something) + 1 --starting position of the values you want
    , charindex(')', @Something) - charindex('(', @Something) - 1 --length of the values you want
    )
```